# why is there a delay in showing the IPs in traceroute?

Tags: traceroute, delay

I use traceroute in windows and as usual I get the delays and the IP addresses of the routeres. In each row, after printing the three delays, it takes a few second before printing the IP address. I wonder what is the reason for this delay in displaying the IP address? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

The traceroute program is trying to perform a DNS lookup (so-called *reverse* DNS) for each address shown, so that it could show a domain name instead.

However, your system's configured DNS server doesn't answer to any of those DNS queries (perhaps it's broken, or just does not have Internet access right this moment) so the program waits until the timeout before it'll give up.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to a `-n` flag that will disable the lookup, and just show numeric addresses?

Comment: Yes, the help text shows `-d` for the Windows version.

Comment: (could be a good addition to the answer - sounds like OP is frustrated by the delay... happy to edit if you're happy for me to)

Comment: +1 for updating the answer to include the -d flag.